# Gronwall's inequality and polynomial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Given $u = u(t) \geq 0, u \in C^{1}[0,\infty)$. Suppose there is a polynomial $f$ with non-negative coefficients such that $$u'(t)\leq f(u(t)).$$ Prove that there exists $T>0,M>0$, both depending on $u(0)$ only, such that $u\leq M, \forall t\in [0,T]$.

Remark: I attempted to use Gronwall's inequality, but because we are not given the boundness of $u$, it is difficult to obtain a desired upper bound in terms of $u(0)$.

Comment: I think there is a problem somewhere in your question, because if $u$ is $C^1[0,\infty[$, it's in  $L^{\infty}[0,T]$ for all $T$

Comment: Not too sure how Gronwall's relates to this one, since it's usually stated with $u'(t) \le \beta(t) u(t)$; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality.

Comment: I also think Tryss's comment is correct.  How then to modify the statement of what looks to hint at an interesting question?

Comment: There was indeed a problem in the statement, I have just updated it. T and M must now only depend on u(0). Maybe someone can even get a more clear statement for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that there is something weird in the statement, but let me try to do something. Assume that we know that there exists $u(t)\in C^1([0,T^*))$ and we want to obtain $M$ and $T$, so $u(t)$ is bounded by M for every time $t\leq T$. As in general $u(t)$ will have a finite time blow up, the point that we want to emphasize here is that we can find a local time and a uniform bound depending only on the initial data (so, the blow up happens later). This scenario may be helpful in many pde problems, where the approximated problems may, a priori, have a time lifespan shrinking to zero.

Assume that there exists $T^*$ and $M^*>u(0) $ such that $u(t)\leq M^*$ for all $t\leq T^*$. Now, we write the equation as
$$
u(t)=u(0)+\int_0^t f(u(s))ds\rightarrow \max_{s\leq t} u(s)\leq u(0)+tf(\max_{s\leq t} u(s)).
$$
Define $y=\max_s u(s)$, and take $u(0)<M<M^*$. We can fix $T$ small enough (depending only on the polynomial $f$ and $u(0)$) so 
$$
p(y)=u(0)-y+Tf(y),
$$
intercepts the axis $u=0$ at the point $M$. In this way, we have a polynomial that encloses an area in the first quadrant. Then, we use the positivity of $u$ and the continuity no get that $u$ can not leave that region for time $t\leq T$.